# AceGen SMSFreeze[] function

Tags: finite-element-method, acegen

I'm quite new to AceGen and I'm not getting the function of SMSFreeze[].
The manual writes the following:

SMSFreeze[symbol,{exp1
,exp2
,{exp3…}..},allOptions]

create data objects that represent elements of arbitrarily structured list of expressions {exp1
,exp2
,{exp3…}..} accordingly to
given options allOptions. New auxiliary variables with the values {exp1
,exp2
,{exp3…}...} and random signature are then
generated and the resulting arbitrarily structured list is then assigned to symbol symbol. The process can be additionally
altered by special options listed below that are valid only for input expressions that are arbitrarily structured lists of
expressions.

Does anyone has a better explanation for me with a specific usecase?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

The primal (there are also others) purpose of SMSFreeze function is to transform an expression into an independent variable for differentiation. E.g. if you write D[f(x),x], "x" obviously has to be a variable not an expression. There are plenty of examples of its use in finite element examples.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to solve [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/250978/large-deformation-of-solids) question?